# How to compile C++ code without linking with kernel32?

Tags: c++, compilation, mingw, dynamic-linking

I compiled the following c++ code using mingw on windows:

```
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string foo = "foo";
    foo.append("foo");
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled using the following command:
`g++ test.cpp -o test.exe -static-libstdc++`

I then viewed the compiled file using dependency walker and I found `kernel32.dll` as one of the dependencies this executable uses. Can I compile an executable without linking to this file?

Comment: Your code won't compile because `momen` is used without declaration.

Comment: @MikeCAT Sorry, I edited the post.

Comment: You're not linking to `kernel32.dll`. You're linking with the C++ runtime library, and that will make calls to the operating system, part of which are in kernel32. Is there an issue with needing that DLL at runtime?

Comment: It should be possible in theory to build without kernel32.dll, as long as you don't access any OS resources, like cin, cout, files, etc.  You're looking for a "Freestanding" build http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf

Comment: Note that freestanding compilers are not required to provide `<string>`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @ChrisMM I am trying to compile a source code that doesn't have any direct access to system calls.

Comment: @moamen in that case it will be unable to do any input/output and will therefore not be of much use.